# Deserialization Performance in Objectify 3.x

Tags: java, performance, google-app-engine, protocol-buffers, objectify

Has anyone done any benchmarks on how entity design effect deserialization of your POJO classes when fetching from the datastore and memcache?

I've been doing a lot of profiling of my code using appstats plus some custom profiling and there seems to be MANY gaps of 10-100's of milliseconds between when the RPC to the datastore/memcache returns and when my next line of code starts running. The only thing in between those is Objectify. My assumption is that most of this time is spent deserializing my entity classes from memcache or creating my entity classes and using reflection to fill them when retrieving from the datastore.

Does anyone know what kind of perf characteristics there are in these cases? Does the design of my entities affect deserialization performance? I.e. many small fields, nested fields, large blobs, etc?

Comment: I would try testing these for yourself.  It is very specific to your data structure, but I would be surprised if a simple data structure took more than 1 ms to de-serialize.  That is 3 million clock cycles, an eternity for a computer.

Comment: Yes - this is exactly my question. When profiling MY code - I see memcache gets (when fetched through objectify) take 100ms yet, the RPC call itself may only be 3-4ms. How do I find out where this mystery time gap is coming from?

Comment: I would start with a profiler like VisualVM or a commercial one like YourKit and see where it is spending most of its time.